# Kubernetes: Connect to the outside world from pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a local Kubernetes cluster on a single machine, and a container that needs to receive a url (like https://www.wikipedia.org/) and extract the text content from it. Essentially I need my pod to connect to the outside world. Since I am using v1.2.5, I need some DNS add-on like SkyDNS, but I cannot find any working example or tutorial on how to set it up. Tutorials like [this](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/10/setting-up-skydns/) usually only tell me how to make pods within the cluster talk to each other by DNS look-up.

Therefore, could anyone give me some advice on how to set up and configure an add-on of Kubernetes so that pods can access the public Internet? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply create your pods with "dnsPolicy: Default", this will give it a resolv.conf just like on the host and it will be able to resolve wikipedia.org. It will not be able to resolve cluster local services.If you're looking to actually deploy kube-dns so you can also resolve cluster local services this is probably the best starting point: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! Just out of curiosity, where did you find this information? I cannot find it by Googling :(

Comment: I have a related issue; your link is 404

Comment: Bruh. 4 hrs of debugging worth 1 line. Thanks, sincerely.

Comment: @YunshengBai you can check here, https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/